# Using TypeScript Interfaces and Types in Apollo typeDefs

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

This might be silly, but I am asking anyway.

I have already defined interfaces and types in TypeScript which I want to use in Apollo typeDefs. I have looked into their documentation but couldn't find anything.

What Apollo documentation says

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    id: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
  }
`;

const server: ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs
});
```

It forces to write types in String format which get converted by `gql` function

What I want to use

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}
```

Is there any way I can use the above interface in Apollo's typeDefs?

Your help is really appreciated, I am kind of in a dilemma to duplicate my type definitions for TypeScript and Apollo.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when using TypeScript, the flow will be reversed -- you'll write your type definitions first and then generate your TypeScript definitions from those. The TypeScript definitions can be generated using something like [Apollo's CLI](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) or [Graphql Code Generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/).